# I am receiving strange output from a MSSQL query via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using the following PHP document below running on my linux server:

```
<?
/*
** Connect to database:
*/

// Connect to the database (host, username, password)
$con = sqlsrv_connect('XXXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXXX') 
    or die('Could not connect to the server!');

// Select a database:
mssql_select_db('Quotes_SQL') 
    or die('Could not select a database.');

// Example query: (TOP 10 equal LIMIT 0,10 in MySQL)
$SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM FederalStockCards ORDER BY ID ASC";

// Execute query:
$result = mssql_query($SQL) 
    or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

// Get result count:
$Count = mssql_num_rows($result);
print "Showing $count rows:<hr/>\n\n";

// Fetch rows:
while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    print $Row['Fieldname'] . "\n";

}

mssql_close($con);

?>
```

But after executing the PHP file by visiting:
http://cinicraft.com/Silverman/mssql.php

I am receiving the following output:

\n\n"; // Fetch rows: while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) { print $Row['Fieldname'] . "\n"; } mssql_close($con); ?>

I'm not quite sure what to make of it, is this output being returned by the MSSQL server?

Comment: try using `<?php` instead of `<?` - it looks like your web page isn't picking up the PHP short tags, and is treating it as HTML.

Comment: thanks for pasting your db credentials in public

Comment: do you provided real credentials for the database? if yes please change it from here and from server also!

Comment: No they were dummy credentials

Comment: please see this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

You have used `sqlsrv_connect` while connecting. And then used all `mssql` functions later on. There is a difference between the two of them as mentioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx.

Use `mssql_connect` instead, stated at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Also, ensure that `mssql` driver is enabled